# how to decode data using MFVideoFormat_H264?

Tags: winapi, directx, ms-media-foundation

I want to decode data using media foundation.

I have read this article:[H.264 Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder)

when I create the decoder how to put the input byte data and get the output byte data?

I do notwant it read from files. i have byte array get from socket and I can play it using vlc how to decode the byte data ? then I can display it.

I searched that each frame starts with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 and I can read each frame bytes and send to the decoder to get right data right?

now according @Romain.R 's example I can get the IMFMediaBuffer but I the Bitmap I can not use it directlly. I need convert it to RGB since it is NV12. how to do it in media foundation or direct2D so I can use gpu to accelerate it?

Comment: This is done using the IMFTransform interface, especially the IMFTransform::ProcessOutput method which one is supposed to call in a loop to get decoded buffers out. You might want to search for sample which demonstrate that https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation

Comment: I have searched about it. but I do not know how to post byte data to the ProcessOutput, do I need to create IMFSample? how to copy data to IMFSample? the sample I searched is to read from device automatically not manually. @SimonMourier

Comment: You have an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761146/microsoft-media-foundation-decode-h264-samples

Comment: What the bounty? What exactly do you need. Have you tested the sample in the link?

Comment: How does this look? https://github.com/roman380/MfEsDecode

Comment: What I exactly need is that I will receive encoded data by MediaCodec in android and I want to display it in `winform` so I need to decode the data. now the question is I am newbie and I do not know how to post the bytes to the IMFVideoDecoder @SimonMourier

Comment: In winform?, so you'll need managed code (C#, VB)? Your question is not clear enough to be able to help efficiently [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am sorry I am newbie. I think what I will do is to using c# (or c++ I will write c++ dll can call it in c# ) get the bitmap( or directly to the mediaelement?)  and show it. @SimonMourier

Comment: the data I received from MediaCodec can be play by `LibVLC`

Comment: `MFCreateSample` a new media sample `IMFSample` and pass it to [IMFTransform::ProcessInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mftransform/nf-mftransform-imftransform-processinput) of the decoder as that sample @SimonMourier showed does. Note, [For video, a sample typically contains one video frame. For audio data, a sample typically contains multiple audio samples, rather than a single sample of audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfsample).

Comment: Have you look at my link or Roman's one? It should be enough as far as I understand from your question otherwise you should enhance the question.

Comment: @SimonMourier I am working on it. when I get the output sample I should convert it to bitmap?

Comment: I have already get the raw data and how to display it ? @RomanR.  

in this article-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014780/extract-rgb32-byte-data-from-imfsample/43014840#43014840

Comment: I have tried and the bitmap is 4 copy in one bitmap.

Comment: and the bitmap only has gray color.

Comment: and there is a lot of black blank area.

Comment: You should post a project reproducing what you want to do and what problem you face  otherwise you will never get efficient help [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: who need the bounty?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. For the question in the title I gave you a link to code I wrote a few years ago that does exactly what title says. But you seem to have other and/or further questions. Here on StackOverflow to rationalize the effort it is required that you ask finite and well defined questions.

Comment: now I think I need is to convert NV12 bitmap to Bitmap that direct2D can DrawBitmap @RomanR. please answer this question and I mark the bounty or it will be expired thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[H.264 Video Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder) Media Foundation Transform decodes H.264 encoded stream with or without hardware acceleration.

[Decode H.264 ES using Media Foundation](https://github.com/roman380/MfEsDecode) shows how to manage the MFT in 100 lines of C++ code.

In the case of hardware acceleration, the transform does decoding on GPU leveraging DXVA, and you would obtain `IMFSample` and `IMFMediaBuffer` output backed by DirectX textures with video frames.

> I can not use it directlly. I need convert it to RGB since it is NV12. how to do it in media foundation or direct2D so I can use gpu to accelerate it?

As documentation says, decoder output is `MFVideoFormat_NV12` or close YUV 4:2:0 pixel formats. You can use another MFT [Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft) to convert between the formats, including to RGB and including with GPU acceleration.

Quite so often you don't need to chain the transforms and manage them directly, you can, for example, use [Source Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/source-reader) to read from media source or byte stream (I guess you can find a suitable stock primitive for H.264/AVC ES), then set desired output format, and pull from the reader having it manage the required MFT chain underneath.

Comment: I have read the Source Reader and it is not for real-time render. what I want to do is the real-time render.

Comment: in IMFTransform it will process output of NV12 not RGB32 and the input is H264

Comment: Another MFT I mentioned, Video Processor MFT, is capable to get RGB from NV12

Comment: now I am trying to create texture2d and display it and I have created but can not display it.

Comment: Can you tell me is NV12 format have to be transformed then it can be use in direct3d11? or the image will not right.

Comment: You obviosuly can use NV12 in D3D11m but D3D11 has its own limitations on resources, I don't remember off the top of my head. For D2D I believe you need to convert to RGB first. If you want to copy into D3D11 swapchain for flipping, I suppose NV12 can be used directly either.

Comment: I can not work out converting to RGB. I am newbie to it. what do you prefer? convert or directly copy into D3D11?

Comment: The productive way to move on with your problem is to create a small project, place it on GitHub and request feedback for this code that builds but needs expert comments. The question of conversion itself is, for example, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580429/868014).